# How to execute method after request some permissions in flutter?

Tags: flutter

Like such case, when press a button, firstly check needed permission status, if granted, execute method, otherwise request needed permission, but after request permission, not like native android, I can get permission status results via callback method, according of these results, I can decide if or not execute method. With flutter, how to do in order to skip check permission status again after request?

PS. another problem is it is possible do the check before runApp(MyApp())? if possible, could anyone show me some example codes.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `permission_handler` package to do this.
[permission handler](https://pub.dev/packages/permission_handler)